# How to prevent a node js file from accessing (reading) using its url?

Tags: node.js, apache

This may sound silly, but I didnt find solution anywhere, I have a shared hosting( I have root access), I installed npm and running a node js application to serve a android app API requests, the file is located at www.mysite.com/path/server.js , now if anyone goes to this link they can read the node js file, it has passwords to my database etc, How do I prevent it from exposing to public?

Comment: don't put it underneath your webroot.

Comment: @tkausl You mean 'public_html' right? if I put it outside 'public_html' can I store and access the images inside 'public_html/path/' ?

Comment: I don't see a reason why not, so yes.